# update contact form 7 hard-coded email address in file

Tags: wordpress

I want to add email address of the recipient to the code of contact form 7 in WordPress. How can I update the email address by adding the hard-coded email address as I only have FTP credentials to change the email id. I can't access the site back-end and the database...?

Comment: Can you give a better description of what you want to do?

Comment: I do not have access to site admin panel and database. I can access only files. So How to set new static recipient email using plugin file.